# How to get validation when saving multiple records with newEntities() CakePhp 3.x?

Tags: php, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.1

For some reason I am not getting any validation errors when saving multiple records. I can grab the errors using print_r($user->errors()); but they are not automatically injected into the form like when adding a single user. According to the [docs](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#validating-entities) "Validating entities before saving is done automatically when using the newEntity(), newEntities()." I am not sure if there is a specific way to set up the form to make it return validation for multiple records or if you have to do special validation in the model for inputs that have indexes or what?

view:

```
<div class="page-wrap">
    <div class="form">
        <h1>Join Now</h1>
        <?php 
            echo $this->Form->create(null, ['controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'addMultiple']);   
            echo $this->Form->input('1.full_name');
            echo $this->Form->input('1.username');  
            echo $this->Form->input('1.email');
            echo $this->Form->input('1.password');
            echo $this->Form->input('1.password_confirmation', array('type' => 'password'));

            if ($current_user['role'] === 1 && isset($logged_in)) {
                echo $this->Form->input('1.role', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => ['1' => 'Admin', '2' => 'Editor', '3' => 'Author', '4' => 'Reader'], 'default' => '4']);
            }   
            echo $this->Form->input('2.full_name');
            echo $this->Form->input('2.username');  
            echo $this->Form->input('2.email');
            echo $this->Form->input('2.password');
            echo $this->Form->input('2.password_confirmation', array('type' => 'password'));

            if ($current_user['role'] === 1 && isset($logged_in)) {
                echo $this->Form->input('2.role', ['type' => 'select', 'options' => ['1' => 'Admin', '2' => 'Editor', '3' => 'Author', '4' => 'Reader'], 'default' => '4']);
            }

            echo $this->Form->button(__('Sign Up'));
            echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
public function addMultiple()
{
    $users = $this->Users->newEntities($this->request->data());
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        foreach($users as $user) {
            if( empty($this->request->session()->read('Auth.User')) || $this->request->session()->read('Auth.User.role') !== 1 ) {
                $user->role = 4;
            }
            if ($this->Users->save($user)) {
                $this->Flash->success(__('You have been added.'));
            } else {
                $this->Flash->error(__('You could not be added. Please, try again.'));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Table:

public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        parent::initialize($config);

```
    $this->table('users');
    $this->displayField('id');
    $this->primaryKey('id');
    $this->addBehavior('Timestamp');

    $this->hasMany('MembershipOrders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'user_id',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
    $this->hasMany('MembershipOrders', [
        'foreignKey' => 'affiliate_token',
        'joinType' => 'INNER'
    ]);
}
public function validationDefault(Validator $validator)
{
    $validator
        ->notEmpty('full_name', 'A full name is required')
        ->add('full_name', 'notBlank', [
            'rule' => 'notBlank',
            'message' => __('A full name is required'),
        ]);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('username', 'A username is required')
        ->add('username', [
            'notBlank' => [
                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                'message' => __('A username is required'),
                ]
        ]);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('email', 'An email is required')
        ->add('email', [
            'notBlank' => [
                'rule' => 'notBlank',
                'message' => __('A full name is required'),
                ],
            'unique' => [
                'rule' => 'validateUnique',
                'provider' => 'table',
                'message' => __('That email has already been used.'),
                ]
        ]);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('old_password', 'You must enter your old password is required')
        ->add('old_password', 'notBlank', [
            'rule' => 'notBlank',
            'message' => __('Your old password is required'),
        ]);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('password', 'A password is required')
        ->add('password', 'notBlank', [
            'rule' => 'notBlank',
            'message' => __('A full name is required'),
        ]);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('password_confirmation', 'Password confirmation is required')
        ->add('password_confirmation',
            'comareWith', [
                'rule' => ['compareWith', 'password'],
                'message' => 'Passwords do not match.'
        ]);

    $validator
        ->notEmpty('role', 'A role is required')
        ->add('role', 'inList', [
            'rule' => ['inList', ['1', '2', '3', '4']],
            'message' => 'Please enter a valid role'
        ]);
    return $validator;
}
```

Comment: I figured out how to get some validation to work, but I have to do everything manually. Is there a better way? I love the fact that when adding a single record the validation is automatically inserted. Why is this not the case with multiple records?

Answer (score 2):

You can use 'addNestedMany()' : http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/validation.html#nesting-validators

Comment: Thanks... I didn't know what it meant by modelless forms and so I looked it up and I think I can figure it out now.

Answer (score -1):

You have to pass the entity object to the `Form->create(...` function, instead of passing `null`as the following:

```
echo $this->Form->create($user, .....
```